# Belgium tourist visa refusal, is appealing worth it or not?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, belgium, tourist-visas, iranian-citizens

My husband and I have applied for Belgium tourist visa on September 17th and we were highly confident that we provided all the necessary documents, especially proving the fact that we will leave the country on the scheduled date. Yesterday we received an email implying that our visa application was refused because the reasons and conditions were not well justified.

> l'objet et les conditions du séjour envisagé n'ont pas été justifiés

We bought flight tickets in advance, but we booked hotel with free cancellation policy to not lose more money in the case of being rejected. The only doubt we had was, not providing any documents showing we are married since all the fund and bank accounts were for one of us (my husband) and I just filled out the application form stating that I am currently studying an MS in Computer Science (last semester) but I provided no evidence whatsoever. I also am a freelance translator and speak over 3 languages fluently, I know it might be unrelated but given that the translation company I work for is quite popular, will it help them understand it is only a tourist visa, being desperate to see Bruges (inspired by the movie, [in Bruges](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780536/) (as silly as it sounds))?

I wonder if we could appeal and explain the situation more clearly for the consulate. I wouldn't risk reapplying again since the fee is quite high. As I searched their website, they provide no information on appealing, does it mean there is no such an option in their embassy in Iran? Would sending an email help?

Further information: I once applied for a schengen visa and traveled to Germany four years ago before getting married. My husband applied for a UK student visa 5 years ago (thrice) and was rejected. I wonder if we are rejected because of that.

Edit: I have read all the related questions, but I guess such questions must be answered individually, I might be wrong)

There is also another reason that could have made them skeptical. We bought our ticket online which was a fairly cheap flight, then we planned to set an appointment online via Belgium embassy website and found out the earliest available date is October 18th, two days before our planned departure date. We sent the embassy an email requesting for an appointment any time earlier than that with a print of our ticket attached. Then they set us another appointment on Sep 17th (they said the email is for urgent cases only)

Comment: I'm confused, have you actually received a clear rejection or not? Were questions raised that you couldn't answer at your appointment?

Comment: @CMaster The bit in French is one of the official rejection motives.

Comment: You can find more details on how to deal with this rejection in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: Beyond that, it rarely makes sense to appeal, it's going to take too long for this trip and is likely to cost more (as you would need legal help to have any chance of success), see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/schengen-visa-refusal-does-it-make-sense-to-appeal

Comment: @CMaster: I received an email indicating that "Dear sir/madame
Please find the notification of the refusal ." with an ttached word document   stating the above mentioned reason". There were no questions, we handed the documents to the officer/Secretary/???, she said this was your first and last time we set an appointment by email and asked if it is okay to me if they send both results to my husband's email.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/schengen-visa-refusal-does-it-make-sense-to-appeal

Comment: UK visa rejection has nothing to do with Belgium (schengen). What is the occupation of your husband? Seems to me that you did not show proper evidence on what you do for your living, and they refused because they think you (both) are going to find a job in Belgium and will not come back. You must prove 100% that you will return to your home country for tourist visa, if not they will refuse. Buying tickets before visa doesnt make much difference.