# Mentioning new date in Schengen visa Appeal

Tags: visas, schengen, france, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens

I hold a Pakistani passport living in Pakistan. I have recently applied my tourist visa in French embassy and they refused on the following grounds:

1. The purpose and the conditions of the proposed visit have not been justified.
2. The information communicated in order to justify the purpose and conditions of the proposed stay is not reliable.
3. Your willingness to leave the Member States' territory before the expiry of the visa could not be established.

Kindly help me which documents should I provide in addition

As I have provided them with all documents required. I can appeal in the next 60 days of refusal and my original travelling date was 28th Dec 2015, I know that appeal takes a lot of time. So, can I change my travelling date from the 28th Dec 2015 to maybe 15th Mar 2016 next year?

Comment: `The purpose and the conditions of the proposed visit have not been justified` What evidence did you provide for this ? On what grounds do you want to appeal ? You are from Pakistan, a high risk country, so you need to provide some water tight evidence for your tourism and that you will return back.

Comment: To restate @DumbCoder's comment somewhat: We cannot help you unless we know precisely what told them you are planning to do and what documents you gave them to support that.

Comment: Hello... thanks for the reply.

personal bank statement, company's letter head, my designation, how long I have been working there, salary slips, paid hotel bookings, flight confirmation, insurance, previous visa copies

as I have traveled to Thailand and Malaysia in the past

Comment: should I also be mentioning my home bills etc. as to prove my solid ties with my country, my home is in my father's name and also the bills.

I can say that as I visited Thailand n' Malaysia on new year's eve, I also wanted to spend my new year's eve in Paris but now with appeal it's impossible, so can I mention any other date in the appeal

Comment: An appeal probably does not make sense, you might just as well submit a new application, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/schengen-visa-refusal-does-it-make-sense-to-appeal

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why lodging an appeal with new dates makes little sense:

- You are effectively lodging a new application, you might as well do that properly. An appeal makes sense if you want to point out a mistake in the way the law was applied, not if you want to provide a whole lot of new information. Most of the documentation you originally submitted (itinerary, etc.) will not be valid anymore and even if you do submit convincing new documentation, the original decision could still be upheld on the grounds that it was the right decision based on the information available at the time…
- You have no idea how long an appeal might last. A member of my family is currently waiting on an appeal for a French long-stay visa (slightly different procedure but still) for over a year. A new application is cheaper and quicker when that's an option.
- Being willing to choose arbitrary dates and wanting to go to France ASAP undermines the credibility of your plans. It appears that you are doing a holiday on New Year's eve each year, that's a very good thing. You could for example go somewhere else this year and reapply next year to France or another Schengen country, joining a letter highlighting that you are going to a different place each year and what you changed since your last application.
- They selected *three* different reasons to refuse the visa. It's not a small issue that could be fixed easily, you will want to review the application very carefully (ideally with the help of a legal professional with expertise in French/Schengen visas) before trying again.

Beyond that, you can have a look at the following questions to understand what the grounds for refusal mean and what you could do differently next time:

- [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten?lq=1)
- [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten?lq=1)
- [Schengen Visa Application: tips for preparing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-tips-for-preparing)