# Schengen visa refused by German Consulate in Chennai, India but no reason given

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, germany, visa-refusals

I applied for a Schengen visa in order to visit my husband who resides in Dusseldorf, Germany.
I submitted all the supporting documents including the travel itinerary, proof of accommodation, the personal covering letter from my husband's bank, salary statements, residence permit and marriage certificate.

My application was refused the day after, with no reason checked in the refusal letter.

How can I contact them to approve my visa?

Is there an email to which I send an appeal?

I only have a month before I want to travel to Germany.

Comment: Did you get BOTH PAGES of the refusal notice and all the check marks were blank?

Comment: @GayotFow I got the impression from other questions on this topic that Schengen refusals often came without an exact reason, just a list of "it may have been one of these reasons..." - am I wrong on that?

Comment: It's very strange to receive a refusal the next day. Exactly where did you submit this application?

Comment: Did you receive any stamp on your passport from German consulate with date and reference number written on it?

Comment: @Moo Schengen refusals are a two page list of check boxes, no text like UK refusals.  Also given the OP's likely locale we have to sort through if the VFS was legit or a fraud, there are LOTS of possibilities when these things happen.

Comment: hi all thanks for your reply. i got two pages of letter one in german the other the englush translation without check box and with the following nine reasons of the refusal

Comment: @Divya Contact them for clarification on which criteria exactly you were refused under. Unfortunately though, you cannot compel them to approve your visa petition. You can appeal. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61843/how-to-appeal-a-german-visa-refusal. My experience has shown me the Germans consulates are the meanest when it comes to SCHENGEN visa applications. They once gave me a visa for exactly five days. I applied at the French embassy and the French cancelled the German SCHENGEN visa and issued me a French one valid for one month.

Comment: There are supposed to be 11 reasons, 11 check boxes. You apparently are missing the 2nd page. But nonetheless you should fax the consulate explaining the issue.