# Schengen visa via the Spanish embassy

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, spain

I applied for a Schengen visa via the Spanish embassy. The visa was refused for two reasons:

(1) Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided.

(2) information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and condition of the intended stay was not reliable.

My question is if I appeal, what documentation do I need to provide. Also do I need to translate my write-up for the consulate to Spanish?

Comment: See also [Schengen Visa Refusal: Does it make sense to appeal?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52725/3221) It is very unlikely that you will get anywhere with an appeal, given the circumstances.