# Schengen visa refusal and appeal process

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

Three of my colleagues and I are applying for a Schengen visa for our trip to Europe. This trip is fully sponsored by our company as our reward for our target achievement. Two of my colleagues are approved while me and 1 of my colleagues didn't get the visa with this reason: the information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

We attached an official letter from the company's HR general manager explaining that our trip is fully sponsored by our company and they will ensure we return to our country but we were refused anyway.

So I tried to email the embassy explaining the nature of our trip. In just one day I got a reply that says that I can reapply (not appeal) with an accompanying letter from our company explaining why the company wants to fully sponsor our trip signed by the president.

Is the appeal process the same with applying for a new visa? My understanding is when we want to appeal, we don't have to submit the same document and repeat the process from the beginning.

I am asking this because the embassy is asking us to reapply and not appeal our application.

Comment: @crayarikar no truth in that. The refusal letter will have mentioned that the OP does in fact have a right to appeal.

Comment: You are right. There is, in fact, an appeal process that depends on the foreign ministry that refused to issue the visa. This is according to the European Commission's webpage here: https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/visa_appeal_en. Though, whether the appeal process is mentioned in the refusal letter or not is something that the OP will know. I shall delete my previous comment to prevent any confusion.

Comment: There is more information here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52725/68121

Answer (score 5):

Schengen visa officials *try* to let all genuine tourists and business travelers in and to keep all illegal immigrants out. But of course they cannot really know what an applicant plans to do. Perhaps not even the applicant really knows if he or she will leave again or not.

So they look for three things:

- **Who pays for the trip and why?** That's the same for you and for the colleagues who got their visa, so apparently it wasn't the problem.
- **What are the reasons for the applicant to return?** The best reason is a stable, well-paid job. Somewhat helpful are dependents who do not travel with you. They're a reason to return, but they might also be a reason to stay in Europe and work illegally.
- **What is the travel history?** Having been in Europe and not having overstayed is good, any incidents are bad.

So you should think if you have documented your circumstances at home properly before you reapply.