# Nigerian Rejected: French Caribbean & Schengen Visa Denial

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, france, nigerian-citizens, guadeloupe

My boyfriend applied for a Schengen Airport Transit Visa from France and the French Overseas Territories Visa and was denied. He is from Nigeria and I am from the US. We were planning to meet in Dominica which is visa free but his flight passes through France and Guadeloupe.

I have a question about the French overseas visa application. When the form asks about entries (single, multiple) what exactly does that mean as I read conflicting information online. He needs to enter Guadeloupe for an over night layover and then would fly to Dominica. Then when leaving Dominica he has a two hour layover in Guadeloupe airport. I understand if the visa is granted it’s for 3 months. In his case would he select single or double entry?

Also how can a Nigerian show ties to their country if they are currently not working and are not married? He finished college last year but the graduate certificates have yet to be issued by the university so he’s in limbo waiting for his certificate so he can then apply for jobs. He has his marks/grades from his last semester of school but they dated in summer of 2021 and the school has given no updates in writing as to when the certificates will be issued so we are stumped as to how to prove this to the French. We are doubtful the French will understand the level of disorganization and lack of documentation which normal in Nigeria.

Lastly the reason given for rejection is he didn’t prove the purpose and conditions of the stay and we think the reason is because the embassy in Lagos lacks familiarity with the French overseas visa because after the rejection he called the consulate in Lagos and was told he should have just applied for the French short stay visa and that visa would cover him in Guadeloupe which is not accurate according to the French website so we think that was a factor for the rejection. In his appeal should we site this as a reason why we think they were wrong?

Also is he allowed to submit additional supporting documents along with his appeal?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/schengen-visa-refusal-does-it-make-sense-to-appeal could be interesting.

Comment: First of all, obligatory warning: have you actually physically met your boyfriend? Sadly, it is a common scam that people seduce you online and then ask for money for the flight, visas, and repeatedly ask for more because there are additional (imaginary) costs. They can be *very* persuasive. Next, is there a reason you are not travelling there? You would have far less issues. Every time you enter Guadeloupe counts as an entry. The return flight may not require entry into Guadeloupe, but then an overseas ATV would be required.

Comment: These two related questions https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten may help you understand deficiencies in his application

Comment: Nigeria has one of the highest visa refusal rates https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/news/visa-statistics-pandemic-effect-short-stay-visas-2020-2021-05-09_en Does your bf have a history of travel outside Nigeria? Maybe not what you want to hear, but if he has no family ties (ie dependents), no job, no assets such as property, and no previous travel history, it will be virtually impossible to prove ties to Nigeria.

Comment: French immigration will deal with applications from Nigeria every day and will be *very* aware of the level of disorganization and documentation.

Comment: as well as the very high incidence of Nigerian citizens trying to sneak into France (and the EU in general) as illegal workers using tourist and transit visa. Hence the high rejection rate and very strict rules.

Comment: Should be a lot easier for you to get a visa for Nigeria and meet him in Lagos than for him to get a visa for basically anywhere. Of course meeting a random person you've never met except some online matchmaking site anywhere is exceedingly risky, and Lagos isn't known for its law abiding citizenry and diligent police force.